# How can I use MySQL Trigger to update quantity field in 'items' table with quantity - quantity_delivered

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can I use MySQL Trigger to update **quantity** field in items table with **quantity-quantity_delivered**  when **quantity_delivered** in the **requests** table is updated ?

Here Is My Query, I have tested but I see its not getting updated, can any one help me please?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER items_update AFTER UPDATE ON requests
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE items 
        SET items .quantity = items.quantity - requests.quantity_delivered
        WHERE items .item_id = requests.item_id;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved by myself like this and its working for me thanks All!

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `quantityTrigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `requests` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE items i
SET i.quantity=i.quantity-NEW.quantity_delivered
 WHERE i.item_id=NEW.item_id;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the new. values in your trigger like this

```
drop trigger if exists items_update;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER items_update AFTER UPDATE ON requests
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE items 
        SET items.quantity = items.quantity - new.quantity_delivered
        where items.item_id = new.item_id;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

As an aside should this be an after insert trigger?